# MYSQL 5.7 table 3 fields DATETIME '0000-00-00 00:00:00' how to alter new structure to DEFAULT NULL

Tags: mysql

MYSQL 5.7 table has 3 fields of type DATETIME '0000-00-00 00:00:00' how to alter new structure to DEFAULT NULL when NOT NULL + DATETIME default set to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. In total more then 190.00 records.

When doing an alter of the structure MYSQL sees that there are more then 1 field with the same problem and will not alter any field.
How can I solve this?

```
CREATE  TABLE  `customers1` ( 
 `customers_id` int( 11  )  NOT  NULL ,
 `customers_date_added` datetime DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `customers_dob` datetime NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `customers_last_modified` datetime DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `customers_active` tinyint( 1  ) DEFAULT  '1'
 ) ENGINE  = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET  = utf8

ALTER TABLE `customers1` CHANGE  `customers_date_added` `customers_date_added` datetime NULL ;
```

I expect and need to correct those datetime fields into NULL and not '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.
Problem I discover is in my case there are more then 1 datetime fields with this old setup.

Comment: What was your SQL Alter command, and what error message did it produce?

Comment: MySQL has a problem with multiple `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` settings in a table, setting to `DEFAULT NULL` must work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to update the rows separately, you cannot use the `ALTER TABLE` command for it. The `ALTER TABLE` command makes it possible to add new rows with `NULL` value, but does not change the rows if not necessary.

```
ALTER TABLE `customers1` 
CHANGE `customers_date_added` `customers_date_added` datetime NULL,
CHANGE `customers_dob` `customers_dob` datetime NULL,
CHANGE `customers_last_modified` `customers_last_modified` datetime NULL;

UPDATE `customers1`
SET `customers_date_added` = NULLIF(`customers_date_added`, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'), 
`customers_dob` = NULLIF(`customers_dob`, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
`customers_last_modified` = NULLIF(`customers_last_modified`, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Here we alter all wrong colums in one statement, then update all `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values in all three columns with another statement.

See also: [NULLIF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

Comment: This is the result I get: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: 1 datetime field also have NOT  NULL in the structure.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Maybe there was a typo, try to execute the command I put in the edited answer.

Comment: I tried it but because `customers_dob` datetime NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  result is: Invalid default value for 'customers_dob'

Comment: It must not affect neither the `ALTER TABLE` nor the `UPDATE` statements. BTW, if "dob" is date of birth, perhaps a `DATE` type would be sufficient,

Comment: try this SET SQL_MODE='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

Comment: `customers_date_added` datetime DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `customers_dob` datetime NOT  NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
 `customers_last_modified` datetime DEFAULT  '0000-00-00 00:00:00', makes it not easy to fix this. Only errors above appears.

Comment: All 3 columns should be altered and updated. It is still not clear to me that which step causes this error - are you trying to insert some data after?
I updated the answer to alter all columns, try that one and let me know if it works.

Comment: The SET command row including the ALTER + UPDATE are now working. THANKS!!